# Polymorphic model who can be both types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `Advertiser` who can be a `brand` or a `distributor` but also the both. In my model I have two boolean attributes to find out which roles can have my `Advertiser`.

The point is that an `Advertiser` - `distributor` have some `has_many` relations that an `Advertiser` - `brand` doesn't have.

Usually I use a polymorphic model to differenciate the roles but in this case my `Advertiser` could be both roles at the same time.

Is there any way the have a different behavior for my model based on an instance attribute value ? 
Something like this maybe :

```
class Advertiser < ApplicationRecord
  if instance.distributor == true
    has_many :managers
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach would not scale well if you have more than two types, but have you considered simply introducing a third "combined" type - i.e. `AdvertiserBrand < Advertiser`, `AdvertiserDistributor < Advertiser` *and* `AdvertiserBoth < Advertiser` (pending a better name...)

Comment: This approach sort-of relies on multiple inheritance, however, which ruby does not support. (i.e. `AdvertiserBoth` *wants to* inherit from `AdvertiserBrand` **and** `AdvertiserDistributor`.) But you could mitigate that by defining the shared logic in modules, and including it to both classes.

Comment: No I haven't considered this approach !  Seems good to me since I only have two types and I didn't think it will be more in the futur.
I make 3 classes and 2 modules to share business logic.
Thanks you Tom :-)

Comment: (By the way, if somebody have another solution I'm still interested :) )

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @TomLord, why don't you flip the inheritance chain, i.e.

```
class Advertiser < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AdvertiserBoth < Advertiser
  # define any association or behavior that you think both of brand and distributor role should have
end

class Brand < AdvertiserBoth
  # define brand-specific relations and behavior
end

class Distributor < AdvertiserBoth
  # define distributor-specific details
end
```

In this approach, **you don't have to define roles as polymorphic or even no need to define any boolean attributes which merely define the role type**. You can also avoid defining any shared modules for the purpose you discussed in the question comment.

You can also eliminate the `AdvertiserBoth` class and put all the logics inside the `Advertiser` class itself if you believe the case could be solved in this way.

The main advantage with this approach is that you can manage all these models in a **single database table**, which is why its called [`Single Table Inheritance (STI)`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance).

Comment: Actually this won't work for me because I want the `AdvertiserBoth` model to have both `Brand` and `Distributor` feature. In another language I would have done a multiple inheritance but in ruby the module inclusion solve my problem in a better way